# Dynamically adding a relative layout into an activity inheriting it's property from a generic layout

Tags: android, generics, android-relativelayout, dynamically-generated

I have a relative layout containing an imageview and a textview under it in my layout folder.
Is there any way to dynamically add a relative layout of the exact same properties in my current activity on the click of a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would go something like this:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_id);
        container.addView(addView);
    }
});
```

However this might not work the way you intended. To make sure the View is added at the position you want, create an empty Layout at that position, then use `container` to reference that Layout and add the `addView` to that Layout. Good luck!